# Why my Spark Streaming program processes so slow?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am currently writing a Spark Streaming. My task is pretty simple, just receiving json message from kafka and do some text filtering (contains TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3, TEXT4). The code looks like:

```
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topics)


    messages.foreachRDD { rdd =>

      val originrdd = rdd.count()

      val record = rdd.map(_._2).filter(x=>x.contains(TEXT1)).filter( x=>x.contains(TEXT2)).filter(x=>x.contains(TEXT3)).filter(x=>x.contains(TEXT4))

      val afterrdd = record.count()

      println("original number of record: ", originrdd)
      println("after filtering number of records:", afterrdd)
}
```

It is about 4 kb for each JSON message, and around 50000 records from Kafka every 1 second.

The processing time, for the above task, takes 3 seconds for each batch, so it couldn't achieve real-time performance. I have storm for the same tasks, and it performs much faster.

Comment: By the way, Spark is micro-batches, not realtime

Comment: Then, what is the advantage of Spark streaming, if it couldn't process in real time?

Comment: How many Kafka paritions do you have? Number of partitions in Kafka = number of paritions in Spark, everything may be processing in one partition

Comment: Spark has checkpointing and write ahead logging for fault tolerance. I'm not too familiar with the workings of Storm, but I think Apache Flink may also be used here if you want true streaming

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have made 3 unnecessary RDD's in this process.

```
val record = rdd.map(_._2).filter(x => { 
    x.contains(TEXT1) && 
    x.contains(TEXT2) && 
    x.contains(TEXT3) && 
    x.contains(TEXT4)
}
```

Also, worth reading. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#performance-tuning

Comment: Thanks, I also tried the above, and I found the performance was quite close. Assuming the filtering criteria is low and most of the records will be filtered out In this case, each filter operation actually reduces the size of rdd, so that the next filter operation would works on much lower size of record, and thus reduces the processing time.